# Who first realized that $\int \frac 1x dx =\ln(x)+c$?

Tags: mathematics, discoveries

Who discovered the non-obvious identity $\int \frac 1x dx=\ln(x)+c$ ? Were power series involved? The series look similar on the opposite sides of $1$:

[$$ \frac 1x =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1+x)^n \text{ for } |x-1|<1 $$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/x)

[$$ \ln(x) = \ln(-1+x)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k(-1+x)^k} \text{ for } |x-1|>1 $$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28x%29)

$$ \ln(x) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(-1+x)^k}k \text{ for } |x-1|<1 $$

Answer (score 24):

> By about 1640, the solution to the "area problem" for curves with equation $Y^n = aX^m$  was known by Fermat  for all  integer cases except when $n = 1, m = -1$.
>
> I.e., the only unsolved area problem was for $Y = \frac 1X$  - the standard equation for the graph of a hyperbola.
>
> In 1647, [Gregoire de St. Vincent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%A9goire_de_Saint-Vincent) showed the following special property for hyperbolas:

[image]

If: $\frac ab = \frac cd$ then $\int_a^b\frac 1x dx=\int_c^d\frac 1x dx$

> In 1649 **[Alfonso Antonio de Sarasa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphonse_Antonio_de_Sarasa)** recognized this feature in Gregoire's work  and connected it to the properties of logarithms. In particular he recognized the following additive property of these measurements **which had previously be a key feature in the study of common logarithms (base 10)**: the area determined by a product of two numbers , bd,  is equal to the sum of the areas determined by b and d separately.

If $\frac ab = \frac cd$ and $a=1$ and $c=1$ then $\frac 1b \not= \frac 1d$, but $\frac 1b + \frac 1d = \frac {1}{bd}$

This is the same as saying what RGB did:
$$\int_{1}^{bd}\frac{\text{d}t}{t}=\int_{1}^{b}\frac{\text{d}t}{t}+\int_{1}^{d}\frac{\text{d}t}{t}$$

$$f(bd)=f(b)+f(d)$$

$$ A^b A^d=A^{b+d}$$

Thus a logarithmic relationship was implied and A was found to be e.

$$ \int_1^b \frac 1x dx = \ln(b)$$
$$ \int_1^d \frac 1x dx = \ln(d)$$
$$ \int_1^{bd} \frac 1x dx = \ln(b)+\ln(d)$$

[Source](http://users.humboldt.edu/flashman/Presentations/Estimations.html)

The [Hyperbolic Angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_angle) "$u$" is defined in relation to the function $\frac 1x$:

[image]

The magnitude of the hyperbolic angle "$u$" is the area of the corresponding [hyperbolic sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_sector) (red above, yellow below) which is ln x since it is defined as the integral of the projection onto the axis from a=1 or y=x to b: $\int_1^b \frac 1x dx=\ln(b)$
[image]

While power series were not involved in the discovery of the natural logarithm, they can be used to show the [relationship between $\frac 1x$ and e](http://www.freestudy.co.uk/analytical/outcome1t2.pdf):

If a function is its own derivative then: $ y=f(x), \frac{dy}{dx}=y$

Such a function is a series: $ y=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=0+1+\frac{2x}{2!}+\frac{3x^2}{3!}+\frac{4x^3}{4!}\dots=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+ \dots$$

If we differentiate $y^p$: $ \frac{d(y^p)}{dx}=py^{p-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$

Since $ \frac{dy}{dx}=y$ it follows: $ \frac{d(y^p)}{dx}=py^{p-1}y=py^p$

Given: $y_1=1+z+\frac{(z)^2}{2!}+ \frac{(z)^3}{3!}+\dots$

$$\frac{dy_1}{dz}= 1+z+\frac{(z)^2}{2!}+ \frac{(z)^3}{3!}+\dots=y_1$$

Let $z=ax$,$\frac{dy_1}{d(ax)}=y_1$ $\frac{dy_1}{d(x)}=ay_1$

$$y_1=y^p= 1+px+\frac{(px)^2}{2!}+ \frac{(px)^3}{3!}+\dots=y_1$$

If we let $p=\frac 1x$ then, $y^{\frac 1x}=1+1+\frac{(1)^2}{2!}+ \frac{(1)^3}{3!}+\dots=e$

And Hence replacing $e^1$ with $e^x$ yeilds:

$e^x=1+x+\frac{(x)^2}{2!}+ \frac{(x)^3}{3!}+\dots$

This all lead to the development of the [Slide Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule) as well as [hyperbolic trig functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455480/how-were-hyperbolic-functions-derived-discovered).

Comment: Awesome (exemplary) usage of the answer-your-own-question aspect of Stack Exchange!

Comment: Too bad now you can't accept your own answer :-)

Comment: @Conifold OPs can accept their own answer -after 48 hours, http://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer, although no reputation is earned, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: it's not a beautiful answer :(